# PyQt4: A class MainWindow as a QWidget for another MainWindow

Tags: python, qt, class, module, pyqt4

I made a `QMainWindow` parent, which has `QLayout`. Inside this `QLayout`, I put a `QSplitter`, and I would like to put a MatplotLib widget and a text editor. Well, I made this specific text editor using a `QMainWindow` and I don´t know how can I add it to my layout as a `QWidget` using the  `addwidget`attribute.

This is a part of the main window where I added a layout:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()
    self.splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
    self.splitter1.setMinimumSize(1100, 250)
    self.splitter2 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
    self.splitter2.addWidget(self.frame)
    self.splitter2.addWidget(self.splitter1)
```

And this is a part of the class that I created for the text editor:

```
class WinTextEditor(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
    def initUi(self):
    self.text = QTextEdit(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.text)

    self.initToolbar()
    self.initFormatbar()
    self.initMenubar()
    self.statusbar = self.statusBar()
```

My question is: is it better to make a class and add it to my layout, or make a new module with the text editor and add it like this. And how can I do it?

Comment: Do you really need two `QMainWindow` ? It's seems that your class `Window` could be a simple `QWidget`.

Comment: My `Window` class it´s my main window.  And `WinTextEditor` is the "widget" that i want to introduce un the other one. I used a `QMainWindow`  for `WinTextEditor` because a `QDialog` is not the appropriate one (i think).